# When is $B^G\backslash(B/A)^G$ finite?

Tags: group-cohomology, galois-cohomology, nonabelian-cohomology

Let $G$ be a locally compact group, let $A,B$ be (not necessarily abelian) connected reductive complex groups equipped with continuous actions of $G$ via algebraic automorphisms. Let $\phi:A\to B$ be a $G$-equivariant closed embedding of algebraic groups. The kernel of the map $H^1(G,A)\to H^1(G,B)$ of pointed sets is in bijection with the quotient $B^G\backslash(B/A)^G$. (See Corollary 1 to Lemma 36 in *Galois Cohomology*, by Serre.) I am interested in conditions that guarantee that this quotient is finite.

I am willing to assume that the action of $G$ on $A$ (resp. $B$) is obtained from an action that preserves a pinning by twisting that action by a continuous 1-cocycle of $G$ in $A$ (resp. $B$), and I am most interested in the case when $G$ is a Galois group or Weil group.

Comment: While a natural question, I think that the answer is that there aren't many results that are both very general and non-trivial.  I don't have a proof of that, but certainly, while I've often needed to know that such quotients are finite, I've seldom been able to do so by appealing to a result that felt essentially cohomological in flavour, rather than appealing to special structure on $A$, $B$, and/or $G$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I certainly agree with the first sentence and do not expect a general cohomological argument, rather I am looking for examples of special cases in which one can prove finiteness.

Comment: I did not notice that you were interested specifically in complex algebraic groups.  In this case, although it's probably too specialised to be of interest, we have finiteness (even of $H^1(G, A)$, let alone of the kernel) if $G$ is $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb C/\mathbb R)$ for some Galois extension $\mathbb C/\mathbb R$, with the action on $A$ coming from a real form of the underlying complex algebraic group.  This is III.§4.3, Theorem 4 of Serre's *[Galois cohomology](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-59141-9)*.